# Angular 3 Nested States

Tags: javascript, angularjs, routes, nested

I need 3 nested views in angular.js. 
The first one calls "tabs". The next templated is the homePage and the third calles ourAim.
Th first and the second works. The third not. When I look at the third url. I see the tabs from first page and the text of theh third one. But I don't see the second view.

```
 .state('tabs', {
  url: '/tabs',
  templateUrl: 'templates/homeTabs.html',
  controller: 'AuthController'
})

.state('tabs.homePage', {
  url: '/homePage',
  views: {
    'menuContent': {
      templateUrl: 'templates/views/homePage.html',
      controller: 'HomeCtrl'
    }
  }
})

.state('tabs.homePage.ourAim', {
  url: '/ourAim',
  views: {
    'menuContent': {
      templateUrl: 'templates/views/homePage/ourAim.html',
      controller: 'AimCtrl'
    }
  }
})
```

How I make the third one correct? I want to see my tabs and my homepage in this page.

Comment: You are overriding `menuContent` in the third state, that causes the problem

Comment: What can I write instead?

Comment: You should have nesting - i.e. `homePage.html` should have `ui-view="something"` which you should refer to in the third view